# Is it permissible to offer Salah with your lower garment overlapped with socks?

Tags: salat

Assalam o alaikum,

Is it permissible to pray with your lower garment (i.e. pants) overlapped with socks? The image displays an example. Jazakallah khair.

Note: The pants are above the ankles while overlapped.[image]

Comment: Why shouldn't it be permissible?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Assalam o alaikum, I was just curious since I don't think I've seen anyone do it.